# responsive height proportional to content

Tags: html, css

i want to get a responsive height in relative to my content.

for example the height responsive to the text inside

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- LINK ZU CSS FILES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="grid-container">
            
            <div class="header">header</div>
            <div class="menu">menu</div>
            
            <div class="content-1">5</div>
            <div class="content-2" >
                <p class="content-text" >lorem500</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
*,*::before,*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        '. header-text header-text header-text header-text menu menu .'
        '. content-1 content-1 content-1 content-1 content-1 content-1 .'
        'content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2 content-2';
}

.header {
    grid-area: header-text;
}

.menu {
    grid-area: menu;
}
.content-1 {
    grid-area: content-1;
}

.content-2 {
    grid-area: content-2;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

i tried the min-height option for the content-2 container but i dont know where im wrong.
maybe have u some other tipps & tricks how i could manage this thing
thx 4 all answers & tipps

Comment: you want your content-2 height to be same as its content? use height:fit-content

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to have a stretching height in relative to the content-text inside the content-2 div

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with

```
.content-2 {
    grid-area: content-2;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

"fit-content" solved the problem. My container-2 stretches in relative with the content-text inside my content-2